# how to use Room database if I need to make more than one table?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

currently I am learning how to use Room in Android. and all the tutorials I follow only make one Table (i.e only one data class)

here is the database and the dao if I want to save only one Table (i.e `Note` object in here)

here is the database data class

```
@Database(entities = [Note::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(DataConverter::class)
abstract class NoteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val noteDao: NoteDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NoteDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): NoteDatabase {

            synchronized(this) {

                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            NoteDatabase::class.java,
                            "note_database"
                        )

                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()  
                        .build()

                    INSTANCE = instance
                }

                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Dao

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    fun save(note: Note)

    @Delete
    fun delete(note: Note)

    @Query("DELETE FROM note")
    fun deleteAllNotes()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY priority DESC")
    fun getAllNotes() : LiveData<List<Note>>


}
```

what if I want to save more than one Table, if for example I want to save Note and Product object into two tables. my question is

do I need to make 2 different abstract class databases like `NoteDatabase` and `ProductDatabase` and also two Daos like `NoteDao` and `ProductDao`  ?

if I can combine it could you please show me the code ?

Comment: You will need one entity per table, and the `entities` property of your `Database` annotation will need to list them all. Whether you have one DAO per entity or combine them is up to you -- Room doesn't care. Any example that has relations will show multiple entities, such as [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.3/MiscSamples/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/misc/onetomany). You do not want multiple `RoomDatabase` classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at the [sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/data/AppDatabase.kt) sample app by google.

```
@Database(entities = [GardenPlanting::class, Plant::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

You will need to include your entity class inside the "entities" list property in @Database. As in the example above GardenPlanting and Plant.

Answer (score 3):

Create a data class with **@Entity** annotation per table. For example, below are two tables: **TableOne** and **TableTwo**

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_one")
data class TableOne(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val title: String
)


@Entity(tableName = "table_two")
data class TableTwo(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String
)
```

Now list those tables as entities in **@Database**

```
@Database(entities = [TableOne::class, TableTwo::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun appDao(): AppDao
}
```